# Radiative cooling time for a black body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Okay, so this is confusing me a bit. How can I calculate the time it takes to cool a perfect black body from an initial temperature $T$ down to equilibrium temperature (say, 3 K for space)?

I know that $$\frac{P}{A}=\sigma T^4,$$ but I'm stuck at getting $t$ out of there.

Comment: You need to know the specific heat, $C$, of your object then use $dU = CdT$. The power, $P$, is $dU/dt$.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without knowing the specific heat? I need this for background work on an SF concept I'm working on, specifically for the workings of deflector shields (think Langston Fields, if you've ever read Mote in God's Eye, but different).

Comment: Theoretically it would take infinite amount of time the reach the same temperature as its surrounding.

Comment: @verp: no. The Langston field converts energy to some other form to store it (defying the second law of thermodynamics in the process!). How it does this is a question for the [SF Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: So if you've got a working Langston Field, you might as well have some other unobtanium-related functionality, thus giving you whatever cooling time fits your story line.  :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie care to expand that into an answer? curious :)